# Прошу помочь с SQL запросом

Tags: sql

Исходная таблица:

```
Numx IFx   Summx
1    True  10
1    True  20
2    False 15
2    True  40
3    False 50
```

В ответе нужно получить:

```
Numx SummAllx SumIFx
1    30       30
2    55       40
3    50       0
```

Вторая колонка ответа SummAllx это суммы колонки исходной таблицы Summx по группам из Numx. Сделать это просто:

```
SELECT Numx, SUM(Summx) AS SummAllx
FROM TestTabl
GROUP BY Numx
```

В колонке SumIFx тоже итоги, но только те, у кого IFx = True. С этим тоже просто:

```
SELECT Numx, SUM(Summx) AS SumIFx
FROM TestTabl
WHERE IFx = True
GROUP BY Numx
```

А как сделать это одним запросом, чтобы получить сразу все три колонки? Пробовал объединять два запроса с помощью UNION. Штука полезная, но такой ответ сделать не получается. Посоветуйте хотя бы куда копать.

База данные MS Access, Пишу на VBA под Excel 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
SELECT Numx, SUM(Summx) AS SummAllx, SUM(iif(IFx = True,Summx,0)) AS SumIFx
FROM TestTabl
GROUP BY Numx
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Способ отлично работает. Раньше я не знал про iif

Answer (score 1):

Например, подзапросом:

```
select
    Numx,
    sum(Summx),
    (select isnull(sum(Summx), 0) from TestTabl where Numx = t.Numx and IFx = 1)
from
    TestTabl t
group by
    Numx
```